# Retornar para uma página com formulário preenchido

Tags: javascript, html, python, aplicação-web, django

Estou usando Django e tenho que implementar o seguinte fluxo:

O usuário preenche as informações de um novo exame, clica em anexar um exame antigo, vai para a tela de busca de exames, seleciona o exame desejado e precisa voltar para a página de cadastro de exame novo (com as informações que já tinha preenchido).

Já fiz a parte dos links de redirecionar para as páginas, mas como posso:

1) Manter os dados da página de cadastro preenchidos ao redirecionar para outras. Pelo que pesquisei tem um [framework de cache do Django](https://django-portuguese.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/topics/cache.html), mas não sei se é bem isso.

2) Passar o id do exame selecionado para a outra página.

Não vou adicionar código pois é mais uma questão conceitual, se souberem me passar qualquer exemplo de algo parecido, ou algum termo que eu possa pesquisar, já ajuda muito.

Edit: consegui retornar para a página com os dados preenchidos usando `onclick="location.href = 'javascript:window.history.go(-2)'"`, que é equivalente a apertar o botão de voltar duas vezes. Espero que assim seja possível passar o id.

Comment: Na verdade a pesquisa de novos exames poderia ser feita através de uma janela modal onde você procuraria o exame propriamente dito e este seria adicionado ao formulário (ou não se a janela modal fosse fachada).

Comment: @GiovanniNunes, também pensei nessa abordagem, mas por já ter pronta a tela de pesquisa foi solicitado ir para a página mesmo :s

Comment: Abre em uma outra janela, não fucncionaria?

Comment: Não pode ser com [page tabs](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_full_page_tabs.asp)?

Comment: @Sidon com page tabs é criada uma cópia da página?

Comment: Vc coloca o que quiser nas `tabs` no link que coloquei no outro comentario vc pode "brincar" um pouco com as tabs, faça isso e vc vai entender

Answer (score 0):

Talvez não seja a melhor das abordagens para solucionar esse caso, mas, ao usuário selecionar o exame, guarda o id do exame na session, quando ele retornar para a página do formulário, verifica se tem um id na session, carrega o objeto pelo id, seta eles com initial no forms.py e apaga essa session de id.

Só tens que atentar para caso o fluxo seja interrompido pro id não ficar setado na session, ou seja, quando entrar nessa página do formulário, mas, não vier do redirecionamento da seleção, apagar o id da session - se tiver algum.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/topics/http/sessions/

Ah sim, não faz redirect por javascript, utiliza o que o django oferece, um dos casos por exemplo, você pode sobreescrever o botão de salvar e continuar.

```
class ClasseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, changed):
        if '_continue' in request.POST:
            redirect('url_name')
        return super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Referência: https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/

Comment: Realmente não é mesmo a melhor abordagem, eu diria que é uma 'bad idea'. :-)

Comment: É que se não pode alterar o fluxo da tela, essa foi a única solução que me veio em mente..

Comment: Não pode alterar o "fluxo da tela"? Como diria o Tadeu: "Qué q isso rapa?" :-)